# Como leer archivos en C++?

Tags: c++, archivo, dev-c++

estoy tratando de leer un archivo y he intentado y buscado en muchos sitios, pero ninguno me aclara nada, voy a dejar a continuación algunas de las maneras que he hecho para intentar leer el archivo y lo que me da de resultado por pantalla.

Codigo principal:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;



struct Libro{
    unsigned long int isbn;
    string titulo;
    string autor;
    float precio;
    int stock, vendidos;    
};

const int TAM = 100;
typedef Libro VectorL[TAM];


void Lectura(string &nombre, VectorL &vector);
void menuPrincipal(char &aux);
void menuConsultas(char &aux);
void buscarISBN(unsigned long long &isbn, VectorL &vector);
void consultaTodo(VectorL &vector);
//funcion c consultas
void insertarLibro();
void venderLibro();
void modificarPrecio();
void menuEstadisticas(char &aux);
//funcion a estadisticas
//funcion b estadisticas

int main(){
    
    VectorL vector;
    string nombre_archivo = "libros.txt";
    Lectura(nombre_archivo, vector);

    
    char eleccion;
    
    menuPrincipal(eleccion);
    
    switch(eleccion){
        
        case 'a':
            menuConsultas(eleccion);
            switch(eleccion){
                case 'a':
                    unsigned long long bISBN;
                    cout << "ISBN del libro a buscar: ";
                    cin >> bISBN;
                    buscarISBN(bISBN, vector);
                    break;
                case 'b':
                    cout << "2";
                    break;
                case 'c':
                    cout << "3";
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    cout << "4";
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 'b':
            cout << "b";
            break;
        case 'c':
            cout << "c";
            break;
        case 'd':
            cout << "d";
            break;
        case 'e':
            menuEstadisticas(eleccion);
            switch(eleccion){
                case 'a':
                    cout << "5";
                    break;
                case 'b':
                    cout << "6";
                    break;
                case 'c':
                    cout << "7";
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 'f':
            return 0;
    }   
}

void Lectura(string &nombre, VectorL &vector){

    ifstream archivo_leer;
    archivo_leer.open(nombre.c_str());
    if (!archivo_leer.is_open()){
        cout << " ---> No se puede abrir el fichero: " << nombre << " <---" << endl;
    }
    else{
        while(!archivo_leer.eof()){
            for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
                getline(archivo_leer, vector[i].isbn);
                getline(archivo_leer, vector[i].titulo);
                getline(archivo_leer, vector[i].autor);
                getline(archivo_leer, vector[i].precio);
                archivo_leer >> vector[i].stock;
                archivo_leer >> vector[i].vendidos;
                archivo_leer.ignore();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Aún quedan muchas cosas por poner pero no os fijéis en todo lo que falta, ya que no lo pongo porque es mucho código, creo que con lo que hay se puede entender, en caso contrario decírmelo y subiré más información sobre el programa. En el caso de arriba me da un error de que no encuentra una función para el comando getline.

Error:
106 41 [Error] no matching function for call to 'getline(std::ifstream&, long unsigned int&)'

Otro intento que he hecho ha sido:

```
    ifstream archivo_leer;
    archivo_leer.open(nombre.c_str());
    if (!archivo_leer.is_open()){
        cout << " ---> No se puede abrir el fichero: " << nombre << " <---" << endl;
    }
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
            archivo_leer >> vector[i].isbn;
            archivo_leer >> vector[i].titulo;
            archivo_leer >> vector[i].autor;
            archivo_leer >> vector[i].precio;
            archivo_leer >> vector[i].stock;
            archivo_leer >> vector[i].vendidos; 
            
        }
    
    }
}
```

En este caso si que compila el programa, pero al leer los datos da unos valores que no corresponden con lo que deberían dar, como por ejemplo ceros en algunas variables o números muy altos en otras variables.

Aquí al final dejo el contenido del .txt el cual quiero que se lea(las comillas es para saber cuando empieza y acaba el archivo):

```
9788401026003
El medallón de fuego
Carla Montero
20.80
13 107

9788466664417
Reina Roja
Juan Gomez Jurado
19.85
21 250

9783764532727
Fuego y Sangre
George R. R. Martin
14.95
17 93
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que `getline` está pensado para leer únicamente cadenas de texto.

Los operadores de extracción dejan de leer cuando se encuentran con un caracter no válido o un separador (espacio, tabulador, salto de línea). El comportamiento de dicho operador de extracción no te permitiría, en principio, leer una línea de texto porque ésta puede contar con un número indeterminado de espacios y tabuladores y únicamente un salto de línea ... gestionar esto con el operador de extracción es complicado.

Así que no puedes usar `getline` para leer datos de tipo numérico ... además tampoco tendría sentido ya que un espacio o un tabulador no forma parte de un número.

Tu primer ejemplo está casi casi bien. Deberías dejarlo así:

```
archivo_leer >> vector[i].isbn;
archivo_leer.ignore();
getline(archivo_leer, vector[i].titulo);
getline(archivo_leer, vector[i].autor);
archivo_leer >> vector[i].precio;
archivo_leer >> vector[i].stock;
archivo_leer >> vector[i].vendidos;
```

Es decir, lees los campos numéricos con el operador de extración y dejas el uso de `getline` para aquellos textos que pueden contener espacios.

No hay que olvidar mover la llamada a `ignore` **antes** de la primera llamada a `getline`, puesto que el operador de extracción dejará el salto de línea en el buffer de entrada y, si no lo eliminas, `getline` leerá una cadena vacía

---

**EDITO**

Añadiría un cambio más.

El tipo `unsigned long int` puede ocupar 32 bytes o 64, depende de la arquitectura del sistema y del compilador. En 32 bits no vas a ser capaz de almacenar el isbn, así que o bien cambias el tipo a `std::string`, o te aseguras de usar un tipo de 64 bits, como `unsigned long long int`

Answer (score 1):

> En el caso de arriba me da un error de que no encuentra una función para el comando getline.
>
> ```
> Error: 106 41 [Error] no matching function for call to 'getline(std::ifstream&, long unsigned int&)'
> ```

Esto sucede porque `std::getline` en efecto, [carece de sobrecarga que cepte un `long unsigned int`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

Estas son las sobrecargas disponibles:

> ```
> template< class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator >
> std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>&
> getline( std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>&& input,
>          std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>& str, CharT delim );
>
> template< class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator >
> std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>&
> getline( std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>&& input,
>          std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>& str );
> ```

Que si quitamos de en medio todo el galimatías de las plantillas (`template`) queda así:

> ```
> std::basic_istream&
> getline( stream_de_entrada&& input,
>          cadena& str, caracter delim );
>
> std::basic_istream&
> getline( stream_de_entrada&& input,
>          cadena& str );
> ```

Es decir: `std::get_line` sólo acepta cadenas de caracteres. Pero no pasa nada ya que puedes usar el [operador de lectura con formato (`>>`) que sí dispone de sobrecarga para leer `long unsigned int`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt):

> ```
> basic_istream& operator>>( short& value );
> basic_istream& operator>>( unsigned short& value );   
> basic_istream& operator>>( int& value );
> basic_istream& operator>>( unsigned int& value ); 
> basic_istream& operator>>( long& value );
> basic_istream& operator>>( unsigned long& value );    
> basic_istream& operator>>( long long& value );
> basic_istream& operator>>( unsigned long long& value );
> basic_istream& operator>>( float& value );
> basic_istream& operator>>( double& value );
> basic_istream& operator>>( long double& value );  
> basic_istream& operator>>( bool& value ); 
> basic_istream& operator>>( void*& value );    
> basic_istream& operator>>( std::ios_base& (*func)(std::ios_base&) );  
> basic_istream& operator>>( std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>&
>                                (*func)(std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>&) );  
> basic_istream& operator>>( basic_istream& (*func)(basic_istream&) );  
> basic_istream& operator>>( std::basic_streambuf<CharT,Traits>* sb );
> ```

Es más, te aconsejo que sobrecargues dicho operador sobre flujos de entrada y salida para poder leer/escribir a archivo o consola:

```
struct Libro{
    unsigned long long isbn;
    string titulo;
    string autor;
    float precio;
    int stock, vendidos;    
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Libro &l)
{
    return o << l.isbn << '\n'
             << l.titulo << '\n'
             << l.autor << '\n'
             << l.precio << '\n'
             << l.stock << '\n'
             << l.vendidos;
}

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &i, Libro &l)
{
    i >> l.isbn;
    i.ignore();
    std::getline(i, l.titulo);
    std::getline(i, l.autor);
    i >> l.precio;
    i >> l.stock;
    i >> l.vendidos;

    return i;
}
```

Con ese código puedes leer y escribir `Libro` en flujos (ya sean archivos o consola) de esta manera:

```
int main()
{
    Libro fundacion
    {
        9788498003116ull,
        "Fundación",
        "Isaac Asimov",
        15.f,
        0, 1000000
    };

    if (std::ofstream archivo{"test.txt"})
        archivo << fundacion << '\n'; // Guardar en archivo

    Libro test;
    if (std::ifstream archivo{"test.txt"})
    {
        archivo >> test;   // Leer de archivo
        std::cout << test; // Mostrar por consola
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVNbbtswEPzXKRYOkMiA6shomziRICA/LQqkN8gPQ1HKojQpUKQRwPCpeoQezOVLshSjLj8MeWY1O7Mr0q77RDkR7fF4hYJyUzMoUfZaMbKtkhPWnEMWQdFWSWIfDNXwjK9K7hOwx4geW8Fq4FK04Qf7V1F4stf142N4GTRqw@U5ToyWKsANl0RDpxjFWIhC22JJf2WwY6LGWvaFw5ND4cxYlRgArmXHFLFSZZl@IDKgUvTRNVzzZRKsK6aNEiChLIGvnGv3dPMibjw9Hk8H@xcKfI4LfIh1ocDnvMCPA0gOMTt@zF5V6ZzA7Cw1QlXFuHHGK7tAqVi6nCynZZqjYKkVGLL/k/bJIxvVZzsMkI83Q06BputAn88tfktQpIPtEKMxoiZWWXhsP07p4X6z@fKwyfPP6/Wd4TwbmcW38Mqf32IxQX/0hFB46nErdxN8/XXVnP7lGaxzfzx0iEaxgfiJxasCRNE33Mn9QrNer/S7XhyWo0ok3RJH@8OaC7i9he@GqJooYGKoTSaRnWQx74v/7bs/624n7pUsZFs@M6bA3uyh31Dt5ak02hkM9bb6p7tL1mBnP3B3lSQnYSCzxeV2ccfjXw)</kbd>.